# SF2, login form appears twice

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I use fos_user_bundle to manage my user. When i go to mysite/login, the login form appears twice.

I override the login.html.twig template.

I change UserBundle:

```
class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
  }
}
```

and: Ressources/views/Security/login.html.twig

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

  {% block fos_user_content %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error|trans }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

        <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" />

        <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" />

        <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
        <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>

        <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
    </form>
  {% endblock fos_user_content %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Did you check if the *layout.html.twig* has the form also? (just wildguessing...)

Comment: In the fosuserbundle layout, there isn't the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my layout.html.twig i gave:

```
{% block container %}
  {{ parent() }}  
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
{% endblock container %}
```

I remove the {{ parent() }} and now, it work.